# Handling rounding errors in matrix multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

**TL;DR: Matrix multiplication for state transition matrix should be norm preserving, but `np.matmul` does not conserve norm. How can I fix this? Is there a better python module to do so?**

I have a right state transition matrix, A, i.e., s(t)A(tau)=s(t+tau)

where s(t) is a column matrix which sums to 1. Also, we know that each row of A adds upto 1 as well.

We know that A^n is also a right state transition matrix for any n in natural numbers.

One way to find the steady state distribution is to compute A^n as n goes to infinity. The following snippet calculates A^(2^n):

```py
    def p_multiplier(A,n):
        B=copy.deepcopy(A)
        for i in range(n):
            B=numpy.matmul(B,B)
        return B[0]
```

This works alright, but for some reason, the summation of rows start not to add upto 1, i.e., numpy starts to leak norm of A[i].

The reason is probably the rounding errors. One quick fix might be to forcefully preserve the norm of each row at each iteration:

```py
def p_multiplier(A,n):
    B=copy.deepcopy(A)
    for i in range(n):
        B=np.matmul(B,B)
        for j in range(len(B)):
            B[j]=B[j]/sum(B[j])
    return B[0]
```

How scientific is this fix? Does scipy or mpmath handle this better?

Edit: To fully fulfill the MWE, you can use the following state transition matrix for A:

```
A=np.asarray([[0.76554539,0.13929202,0,0,0.09516258],[0.04877058,0.76996018,0.18126925,0,0],[0,0.09516258,0.76554539,0.13929202,0],[0,0,0.13929202,0.67943873,0.18126925],[0.09516258,0,0,0.04877058,0.85606684]])
```

Comment: Also, if there is a latex support for stackoverflow, that would be great.

Comment: Please post example arrays for `s` and `A`, as well as the expected output.

Comment: @AJH ```s``` is arbitrary and it doesn't come up in steady state distributions, because regardless of your initial state, you should reach the same steady state distribution. I will add an ```A``` though.

Comment: Your input matrix `A` does not have a sum close to 1 for each line because there are not enough digits. Can you please share the matrix values with more digits like ~14 digits instead of 8~9?

Comment: Calculations with floats are not 'exact'.  People often complain about the near zero values jn `matmul(A, inv(A))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the operation is **not numerically stable**. As a result it *quickly diverge* (exponentially) to 0 or infinity even with relatively-small values of `n` like 70. You can use a **diagonalization method based on eigenvalues** (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287716/compute-power-of-a-matrix-a-as-n-rightarrow-infty) for more informations) which is far more numerically stable.

```py
def stable_multiplier(A, n):
    d, P = numpy.linalg.eig(A)
    return (P @ numpy.diag(d**n) @ numpy.linalg.inv(P))[0].real
```

The number of lost (decimal) digits is in `O(log10(n))` so the error is linear to `n`. Note that if `n` is big like > 1000, then you need to be very careful about the numerical stability of the overall algorithm, especially if it is an iterative process (with at of iterations). For more information, please thread [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation).

Comment: Thanks! This actually solves my question. Now I remember I used the eigendecomposition for this specific purpose before. Sorry for the bad question :)