# Matrix Mutliplication should converge, but it doesn't

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvalues of multiplication between matrices of this kind:

```
import numpy as np

μ=1.5
σ=0.5
m=np.random.normal(μ,σ)

P=[[-1, m, 0.1, 0.1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]] #matrix

n=200

for i in range(n):
  m=np.random.normal(μ,σ)
  T=[[-1, m, 0.1, 0.1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]
  P=np.dot(T,P)

l,v=np.linalg.eig(T)
λ,w=np.linalg.eig(P)

print(l)
print(λ)
```

Being three of the eigenvalues of the matrix T lower than 1 (in module), I expect something similar from the eigenvalues of the matrix product P, in particular that the three eigenvalues lower than 1 will correspond to eigenvalues of P which decreases and converge to 0 with n increasing. In fact, this is true until n=40. Then it doesn't work anymore.
I'm sure there is something wrong in the algorithm and not in the math because for σ=0 P would be the product of n identical matrices with eigenvalues lower than 1. But the eigenvalues of P diverges.

Comment: I bet on numerical instability of your matrix power algorithm. What about using this one https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html based on squaring to do less multiplications. Do you get something more accurate when plugging it in?

Comment: The question is a bit similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808365/handling-rounding-errors-in-matrix-multiplication-in-numpy/71808966). At least the answer talk about the loop divergence and why diagonalization based on eigenvalues should be computed instead.

Comment: You've been both clear, but actually my main problem is related to the case when I try to introduce the noise. I won't be able to use a matrix power algorith then.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear. I'm editing the post

Answer (score 0):

Your `T[i]` is not guaranteed to have eigenvalues less than 1

Add an assertion and you will see when it violates the assumption

```py
import numpy as np

μ=1.5
σ=0.5
m=np.random.normal(μ,σ)

P=[[-1, m, 0.1, 0.1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]] #matrix

n=200

for i in range(n):
  m=np.random.normal(μ,σ)
  T=[[-1, m, 0.1, 0.1],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]]
  assert np.all(abs(np.linalg.eigvals(T)) < 1)
  P=np.dot(T,P)

l,v=np.linalg.eig(T)
λ,w=np.linalg.eig(P)

print(abs(l))
print(λ)
```

Being a stochastic system even violating the constraint sometimes it can converge, but it requires some careful analysis of the expected values of the sequence.

The matrix structure resembles the controlable canonical form in linar dynamic systems [[1]](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece486/fa2017/documents/lecture_notes/state_space_realizations.pdf).

But since the matrix T sometimes have eigenvalues larger than 1, the reasoning you suggested does not apply in this case.